# How to checkout some directories by "git svn"?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My official repository is under svn, I want to use `git svn` to commit back svn.

My original process

```
git svn -q "http://r/svn/libRelease" lib
git svn -q "http://r/svn/appRelease" app
```

Is it possible to combine these two command into one?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in your other question ("[How to combine multiple svn trunk sub-tree into one git-svn repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57362604/6309)"), that would not be practical.

Especially if you want to be able to send commit back to those original Subversion referentials.

You can define a parent Git repository on top of those two cloned folder though, to keep track of the root commits made in each subrepos.
But that would not be related to any Subversion repository.