# How to combine multiple svn trunk sub-tree into one git-svn repository?

Tags: git, git-svn

I want to use git-svn to sync svn repository. The svn repository layout is

```
svn/prjA/trunk
svn/prjA/branches
svn/prjB/trunk
svn/prjB/branches
```

Use the following commands will separate into two git repository.

```
git svn clone https://host/svn/prjA/trunk prjA
git svn clone https://host/svn/prjB/trunk prjB
```

And the layout will be

```
prjA/.git
prjA/...
prjB/.git
prjB/...
```

If it possible to combine these into one git repository and sync to two sub-directories of svn?
And the expected layout like following:

```
.git
prjA/...
prjB/...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to merge multiple Git repositories together, as in "[Combining multiple git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618113/6309)"

But that won't give you a git-svn repo, only a Git one with no more link back to those initial Subversion repository.

So keeping them separate (and work with a parent repo and symlinks for instance) remains the safest way to keep the ability to `git-svn dcommit` whenever you want from one of those Git repositories to their corresponding Subversions referentials.